# I need to remove /en from url in magento 2

Tags: magento2

When I click on category from homepage I found my URL format like this `example.com/en/category`.

I need to remove the **/en** from URL.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add `Preference` to `<Vendor>/<Module>/etc/di.xml`:

```
<preference for="Magento\Store\Model\Store" type="<Vendor>\<Module>\Model\Store" />
```

than override the following `protected` function.

```
protected function _updatePathUseStoreView($url)
{
    if ($this->isUseStoreInUrl()) {
        $url .= $this->getCode() . '/';
    }
    return $url;
}
```

with below code:

```
protected function _updatePathUseStoreView($url)
{
    if ($this->isUseStoreInUrl()) {
        if($this->getCode() == 'default'){
            $url .= '/';
        }else{
            $url .= $this->getCode() . '/';
        }

    }
    return $url;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set: `Store -> Configurations -> General -> Web -> Url Options -> Add Store Code to Urls to 'No'`

Note: Please make sure you are not running multi-website multi-store structure using this setting as it may stopped working after changing it.

Answer (score 0):

When we set up a Magento store, it will pick the default Title and Meta Description and we need to edit these to optimize for SEO. So first Navigate to Magento 2

> admin >> Content >> Design >> Configuration >> URL option Set to No

[image]

For more reference [Click here](https://www.semrush.com/blog/top-10-important-seo-tips-for-your-magento-2-e-commerce-website/)